# Breaking out of Play 'run' in IntelliJ sbt shell

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.0

When starting up a *Play* server in the an IntelliJ project using the *sbt shell*, you get the prompt:

```
[IJ]sbt:app> run

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

However `Enter` does not stop it and `Ctrl-C` kills the entire shell, reloading sbt. What is the proper way to exit and return to the sbt prompt?

Answer (score 9):

It appears `Ctrl-D` terminates the *Play* server and return control to the sbt shell

Comment: This didn't work for me using 'runProd'. Even startup says "(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)"

Comment: this didn't works for me, ^+D is attach to debugger.